# How to jump to a file in the Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I love the Solution Explorer > Right-click > "Open Containing Folder" feature of the PowerCommands extension for Visual Studio 2010. I want the equivalent of a "Jump to location in Source Control Explorer" feature. How can I find out the location in TFS of a given open file, or a file in the solution explorer (or a file in the solution navigator in you have the [Productivity Power Tools extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef))?

The best answer would be a couple of mouse clicks and no keyboard. Next best answer would be a hotkey mapping.

The only solution that I have found so far is to use the Productivity Power Tools extension which has the feature "Find in Source Control". A file in the results list can be right-clicked to "Open folder in Source Control Explorer". The drawbacks to this solution is that is takes many clicks, and the search results can match more than one file if files exist with the same name in different folders.

Comment: I'm curious: Did you ever implement it? =)

Comment: Haha. I wish. But if you have VS 2013 you can use [VSCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece) as psulek [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20470975/224976)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try Visual Studio extension [VSCommands for Visual Studio 2012](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/). It has feature called **Locate in TFS**. This will add new button to Solution Explorer **Locate in TFS** which opens active selected file/folder in TFS Source Control Explorer.

Comment: Do you know where I could find this in Visual Studio 2013? I tried to find commands in the "customize" popup -> commands -> toolbar -> VSCommandsToolBar but I did not find any option called "Locate in TFS" in it.

Comment: Did you download extension for Vs2013 from [Vs Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece) ?

Comment: Sorry it works! I was trying to find how to add a custom button in my top toolbars but there's no need since it's already there... silly me!

Comment: only supports VS2013. try [cat5dev's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26025029/426315) for a plugin that that supports 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 but not VS2017

Answer (score 16):

There is a *stand-alone* extension that you can download, called **Locate in TFS**, within Visual Studio.

> **["Locate in TFS" on TFS Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5cc44f63-4ea8-4c17-8aa4-95037a2d32ef)**
>
> **["Locate in TFS" on GitHub](https://github.com/alexcpendleton/Pendletron.Vsix.LocateInTFS)**

This also works on files that you "Exclude from source control", as many developers do with the web.config files.

[psulek's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20470975/2615152), above, mentions this as part of VSCommands, but I prefer the stand-alone extension.

Comment: This has helped me immensely today.

Comment: Currently supports 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 but not 2017

Comment: Is there a tool or efficient way for the reverse? Going from a file in Source Control Explorer to Solution Explorer?

Comment: @itsho Now available from the same author for VS2017+ https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexPendleton.LocateinTFS2017

Answer (score 5):

Feature request has been raised with Visual Studio team. Read [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2050851-add-context-menu-item-in-solution-explorer-to-open)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. All those looking for this feature should go to the link provided and add their votes

Comment: Sadly the link has rotted.

Comment: never heard that term in this context, very applicable (rotted indeed, and sad as well)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's probably too late. See [TfsExt](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ed973813-8f05-4367-8f5e-798fa98a05f9) extension for vs2010

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible, but it's a good suggestion.

These two examples show how to use the Visual Studio Extensibility APIs to access the TFS Source Control Explorer APIs.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhintz/archive/2006/02/03/524312.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2008/07/09/working-on-tfs-sdk-improvements.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links. They are very helpful. If I feel ambitious I might take on the add-in myself!

Answer (score 1):

For **Visual Studio 2013** try lightweight extension [TfsExt13](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d66c95b6-3664-4ec3-a4ae-9196cdc6176c)

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2022, use this one: [Locate in TFS 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zhenkas.LocateInTFS)