# How to show/select the team foundation currently working project in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, project, azure-devops, visual-studio-project

I got a little problem with visual studio 2012. The annoying problem is that if iam working on any project however visual studio 2012 **doesnt mark/show me the currently project** in the Team Foundation list(Dont know the name) where iam working at. Is there a way to fix this?

Its working fine in vs 2010 btw.

[image: Team Foundation projects]

I know that i can hover mouse over this 'tablabel' and see the path, but **it takes too long** to go there manuall (The Path looks like this...C:\tfsProjectsMB\    example\another example\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder...\My Project).

[image: Name of one project]

It doesnt select/open/show the project where iam currently working at...

[image: How it should look when iam working on a project]

This is how it **should** look like

Anyone any idea? Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this feature was left out of VS 2012 and has been requested here:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2050851-add-context-menu-item-in-solution-explorer-to-open

You can do something similar using VS Productivity tools as outlined here:
[How to jump to a file in the Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432137/how-to-jump-to-a-file-in-the-source-control-explorer-in-visual-studio)

This may also be of some assistance:
**Tools -> Options -> Source Control ->Visual Studio Team Foundation Server -> Open Source Control Explorer to the most recent folder**

[image]

There is also this setting for the Solution Explorer that used to be on by default in 2010.
**Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> Track Active Item in Solution Explorer**
[image]

You mention both VS 2013 and VS 2012 in your question.  In VS 2013 you can go to Team Explorer and right click your open solutions to jump to them in source:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the word 'visual studio 2013' to 'visual studio 2012'. I will test it on Thursday in the office :).